# Excel VBA prevent deletion of cells but allow edit

Tags: vba, excel

I have made a spreadsheet which a user can enter a postcode and a quantity into 2 cells and I have other cells doing calculations and displaying the results.

I have added some VBA to prevent anyone from deleting rows and columns but I would like to prevent deletion of any cell within a range but also allow a user to make changes to certain cells but also prevent editing of cells with formula in there.

In cell `E4`, the user can enter a postcode. In `E6`, the user can enter a quantity. These can be edited but not deleted. `E8:E9` and `E11:E14` are all drop down lists (validation) which hold data from lists. These can be changed using the drop down but not deleted.

`L10:L14`, `L16`, `L23:L27`, `L29`, `L30:L33` can all have their data edited but not deleted.

What would the VBA for this look like? I guess it would use the `Worksheet_Change() event`.

Comment: Why not protect the worksheet? That ways user can edit the cells but wont be able to delete them?

Comment: Tried that and i was still able to delete the contents of E4.  I have a value in there they can change which i want them to do but not click delete and have an empty cell

Comment: So you are not talking about "Deleting" a cell but clearing the contents of the cell...

Comment: What if the user enters something by mistake and wants to delete it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? Users can edit cell `E4` and `E6` but they cannot leave it empty. I am also assuming that the cell are not empty before hand.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E4")) Is Nothing Then
        If Len(Trim(Range("E4").Value)) = 0 Then Application.Undo
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("E6")) Is Nothing Then
        If Len(Trim(Range("E6").Value)) = 0 Then Application.Undo
    End If

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

> Thanks that is what i want to do. What about the other ranges? Is it just a case of loads of IF THEN or can we use a CASE and loop through? – AdRock 2 mins ago

Add/Delete cell addresses from below as applicable.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E4,E6,E8:E9,E11:E14,L10:L14,L16,L23:L27,L29,L30:L33")) Is Nothing Then
        If Len(Trim(Target.Value)) = 0 Then Application.Undo
    End If

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks that is what i want to do.  What about the other ranges?  Is it just a case of loads of IF THEN or can we use a CASE and loop through?

Comment: One moment.. updating the above code :) The above was just an example

Comment: That is spot on.  Thanks very much.  One last thing just to finish my sheet perfectly, is there a way i can add this this VBA, prevention of deleting cells or editing them.  These cells contain formulas and deleting them will impact the whole sheet.  The cells are E16:I34, L18, L28 and L30.

Comment: Lock those cells and protect the sheet. :) Do remember to keep the other cells unlocked.

Answer (score 1):

You are partly right but Worksheet_Change() is triggered after the change, so after the deletion.
What I'd do is to have a hidden sheet to store the values entered by the user and then you can check in Worksheet_Change() whether the new value is empty (deleted) or not.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$E$4" Then
        ' check the previous value on the hidden sheet here, if changed, then save it, if empty, then restore it
    End If
End Sub
```